# Prime new topic subscribers with old messages in Apache Artemis

Tags: activemq-artemis, durable-subscription

I'm configuring an Apache Artemis message-broker. The broker will accept big files and downstream consumers access the topic to process the latest files. Now I'm wondering how to make the latest files available for dev-runs. Because the messages only arrive a few times a day, the test runs would need to access the last few sent messages and can't wait for the next.

For production and staging-systems, I found that durable subscriptions work fine. I've adapted an Apache Camel config to serve as an illustration. Here are two consumers that receive messages, each using a durable subscription:

```xml
<route id="inbox">
    <from uri="file:inbox"/>
    <to uri="activemq:topic:testing"/>
</route>

<route id="outbox-staging">
    <from uri="activemq:topic:testing?clientId=staging&amp;durableSubscriptionName=staging"/>
    <to uri="file:outbox-staging"/>
</route>
<route id="outbox-production">
    <from uri="activemq:topic:testing?clientId=production&amp;durableSubscriptionName=production"/>
    <to uri="file:outbox-production"/>
</route>
```

This is fine. If a consumer is offline it will pick up messages when it comes back online. Now if another consumer joins for testing;

```xml
<route id="outbox-testing" streamCache="true">
    <from uri="activemq:topic:testing?clientId=my-local-consumer&amp;durableSubscriptionName=my-local-consumer"/>
    <to uri="file:outbox-local"/>
</route>
```

because the subscription didn't exist before, the consumer will have to wait for new messages. What I'm looking for is new subscribers to be immediately primed with the available messages. I found different names for the concept such as `prefetchPolicy`, `consumerWindowSize`, or "retroactive consumer". But it's unclear to me which terms apply to Apache Artemis and how to set them up because the examples mostly refer to Apache ActiveMQ.

How can a configure Artemis so that a consumer joining on a new subscription gets past messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`prefetchPolicy`](https://activemq.apache.org/what-is-the-prefetch-limit-for.html) doesn't apply to ActiveMQ Artemis. It's for ActiveMQ 5.x.

The [`consumerWindowSize`](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/flow-control.html) does apply to ActiveMQ Artemis.

However, neither `prefetchPolicy` nor `consumerWindowSize` apply to this situation as they're both related to "flow control" and have nothing to do with putting "missed" messages onto a JMS topic subscription.

The "retroactive consumer" feature is for ActiveMQ 5.x. A similar feature (called "retroactive address") will be available in ActiveMQ Artemis 2.11. It was implemented as part of [ARTEMIS-2504](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-2504).

Therefore you have a few options:

1. Wait for ActiveMQ Artemis 2.11 to be released (should be released in January).
2. Build your own version of ActiveMQ Artemis based on the `master` branch which includes the retroactive address feature.
3. Modify your test environment so that new subscribers don't have to wait so long for messages (e.g. send them more frequently).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! Nice to hear it's going to be available and I can wait until January.